# filter sqlite query based on counts of pairwise interactions

Tags: sqlite, relationship

I am trying to filter a somewhat involved sqlite3 query using a pairwise association table. Say I have these tables (where pet_id_x references an id in table pets):

```
[pets]
id | name    | animal_types_id | <additional_info>
1    Spike     2
2    Fluffy    1
3    Whiskers  1
4    Spot      2
5    Garth     2
6    Hamilton  3
7    Dingus    1
8    Scales    3
.    .         .
.    .         .

[animal_types]
id | type
1    cat
2    dog
3    lizard

[successful_pairings]
pet_id_1 | pet_id_2
1          4
2          4
2          8
3          2
3          4
4          5
4          6
4          7     
5          6
5          7
6          7
.          .
.          .
```

A toy example for my query would be to get the names of all dogs which meet certain constraints (from columns within the pets table) and have > 2 successful pairings with other dogs, resulting in:

```
name  | successful pairings
Spot    6
Garth   3
```

As per the above, the total counts for each id need to be combined from pet_id_1 and pet_id_2 in successful_pairings, as an id may be represented for a given pairing in either column.

I am new to sql syntax, and am having trouble chaining queries together to filter based on conditions distributed across multiple tables.

Comment: Show the SQL you would use if the `successful_pairings` table were not special.

Comment: @CL. can you explain what you mean by "special"?

Comment: Your problem appears to be that have to handle the pet IDs in two columns. Assume you need to handle only one column.